# Asp.net ajax control toolkit html editor content disappears

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, jquery-ui-sortable

I am doing a design screen for my customers and i use jquery sortable portlets.
i put the html editor each column.When u write something into the editor then drag drop the portlets the editor's content is disappearing.After droping it,i change the active mode of editor to preview and design,then i see that content is there.How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I play now a little with the [jquery sortable portlets](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/portlets.html) and I notice that its not just move the position of each div, but redesign the full struct of the divs on each drag-drop.

This is mean that is probably copy/paste the inside div on every moving action.

Now your editor is initialize what its show, and from the moment that the portless is move the div content to other possition, the initialize from the editor is lost.

**To gain it again I suggest to reinitialize the editor after any drag-drop.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.well,how can i initialize the editor ?

Comment: @cisci what editor do you use ? please give me and the url that you get it.

Comment: Aristos thanks for your interest.The url is    http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/  The Default html editor of asp.net ajax toolkit.

Comment: @cisci I do not know how this editor works. Is complicate and fully automate by asp.net. Ether you search on the source the function that initialize the editor with javascript, ether you find some other simpliest. This editor how ever is attach big overhead, view the source of your page to see what I mean. I use the http://ckeditor.com/ and the tinyeditor.

Comment: Thanks Aristos i will examine those editors...Thanks so much.